# How to inherit model from web_studio

Tags: python, odoo

I created a Model in `web_studio` -> `x_shippingcountries` and I want inherit this model but this won't work. No methods will be called.

Setup: Odoo 13

I have the following in  `__manifest__.py`

```
depends': [
    'base',
    'idx_elasticsearch',
    'web_studio'
],
```

My model in odoo 13

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, api

class ShippingCountries(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'x_shippingcountries'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        # hook creation
        _logger.debug("Settings Countries: Queue.hook.create")
        res = super(ShippingCountries, self).create(vals)
        return res

    def write(self, vals):
        # hook writing
        _logger.debug("Settings Countries: Queue.hook.write")
        res = super(ShippingCountries, self).write(vals)
        return res

    def unlink(self):
        # hook deletion
        _logger.debug("Settings Countries: Queue.hook.unlink")
        return super(ShippingCountries, self).unlink()
```